# Controlling Kodi from Browser

Tags: python, node.js, kodi

I am currently building a media website using node js. 
I would like to be able to control **Kodi**, which is installed of the server computer, remotely from the website browser.
How would I go about doing this? My first idea was

- to simply see if I could somehow pipe the entire Kodi GUI into the
  browser such that the full program stays on the server
- and just the GUI is piped to the browser, sending commands back to
  the server;

however, I could find little documentation on how to do that.

Second, I thought of making a script (eg Python) that would be able to control **Kodi** and just interface node `js` with the Python script, but again,

I could find little documentation on that.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank You!

Comment: You could either just integrate with kodi's jsonRPC interface or build your own webinterface, but that would need to run on your kodi instance https://github.com/xbmc/chorus2

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go to settings -> services -> control and then the 'remote control via http' settings? I use this to login to my local ip e.g. 192.168.1.150:8080 (you can set the port on this page) from my browser and I can do anything from there